# How can I get an image in a Bootstrap column to sit tight against the viewport edge?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I'm using bootstrap and I'd like to get an image out of my container so that it hits the edges. I already tried with relative and absolute position but I can't find the trick. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about" class="about">
  <div class="container-fluid py-3 py-md-0">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="about__content d-flex h-100 flex-column justify-content-center text-white">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-md-4">About <span class="text-primary">us</span></h1>
          <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto consectetur distinctio ea iure modi nostrum rem sunt! Eligendi, laudantium, quis.</p>
          <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus autem deserunt doloribus earum, in maiores minus modi natus non provident qui quos reiciendis soluta veniam voluptas voluptatibus? Aut, culpa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="about__image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x300" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this. A simple one, without messing up your layout too much, would simply be **a negative margin** applied with a custom class. We'll use the variable Bootstrap uses for the column padding, and we'll increase image size by the same amount to keep the left edge where it was.

Class name follows Bootstrap's convention of `<descriptor>-<position>`. We'll combine it with the fluid image class to achieve adequate specificity.

```css
.img-fluid.shifted-end {
  margin-right: calc(- var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
  max-width: calc(100% + var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about" class="about">
  <div class="container-fluid py-3 py-md-0">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="about__content d-flex h-100 flex-column justify-content-center text-white">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-md-4">About <span class="text-primary">us</span></h1>
          <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto consectetur distinctio ea iure modi nostrum rem sunt! Eligendi, laudantium, quis.</p>
          <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus autem deserunt doloribus earum, in maiores minus modi natus non provident qui quos reiciendis soluta veniam voluptas voluptatibus? Aut, culpa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="about__image">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800?grayscale" alt="" class="img-fluid shifted-end">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Another strategy would be to apply the image as a background on **a pseudo-element of the container**. This cleans up the markup a bit, requiring only a little CSS.

```css
.bg-custom {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-custom:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1200/300?grayscale');
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="about" class="about">
  <div class="container-fluid py-3 py-md-0 bg-custom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="about__content d-flex h-100 flex-column justify-content-center text-white">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase fw-bold mb-md-4">About <span class="text-primary">us</span></h1>
          <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto consectetur distinctio ea iure modi nostrum rem sunt! Eligendi, laudantium, quis.</p>
          <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus autem deserunt doloribus earum, in maiores minus modi natus non provident qui quos reiciendis soluta veniam voluptas voluptatibus? Aut, culpa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
 Unfortunately, none of these tips work for me. For the first tip, webpack doesn't compile because of the "(- var)" which is weird because it works for you. The second option doesn't work either, the image still stay in the container. I forgot to mention that I changed the max-width of the .container-fluid to 1600px, I don't know if that matters.

Comment: It does matter. Update your question to make that clear.